# Creating a form that allows user to save Progress and retrieve to finish later

Tags: expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine. 
I'd like to create a multi page application from that allows a logged in user to save and complete in stages, if required.

I don't think Solspace or Dev Demon forms allow this out of the box so I am looking for any suggestions on the best way to do this. Would safecracker work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible using the SafeCracker module:

http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/214505/

Answer (score 0):

Solspace's Freeform Pro will let you do multi-page forms.

Answer (score 0):

I use Safecracker. There's one bug (maybe fixed in 2.5.3): in the second form some field types such as checkboxes and radios get overwritten and blank out. I had to add hidden fields to keep this data.